# Really Basic S3 Upload credentials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm giving Amazon Web Services a try for the first time and getting stuck on understanding the credentials process.

From a [tutorial](https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx1K43Z7KXHM5D5/Uploading-Files-to-Amazon-S3) from awsblog.com, I gather that I can upload a file to one of my AWS "buckets" as follows:

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new

s3.bucket('bucket-name').object('key').upload_file('/source/file/path')
```

In the above circumstance, I'm assuming he's using the default credentials (as described [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsRuby/latest/DeveloperGuide/prog-basics-creds.html) in the documentation), where he's using particular environment variables to store the access key and secret or something like that.  (If that's not the right idea, feel free to set me straight.)

The thing I'm having a hard time understanding is the meaning behind the `.object('key')`.  What is this?  I've generated a bucket easily enough but is it supposed to have a specific key?  If so, how to I create it?  If not, what is supposed to go into `.object()`?

I figure this MUST be out there somewhere but I haven't been able to get it (maybe I'm misreading the documentation).  Thanks to anyone who gives me some direction here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because S3 doesn't have traditional directories, what you would consider the entire 'file path' in your client machines, i.e. \some\directory\test.xls becomes the 'key'. The object is the data in the file.

Buckets are unique across S3, and the keys must be unique within your bucket.

As far as the credentials, there are multiple ways of providing them - one is to actually supply the id and secret access key right in your code, another is to store them in a config file somewhere on your machine (this varies by OS type), and then when you are running your code in production, i.e. on an EC2 instance, the best practice is to start your instance with a IAM Role assigned, and then anything that runs on that machine automatically has all of the permissions of that role. This is the best/safest option for code that runs in EC2.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response; I feel like I'm understanding the idea behind AWS much more.  To clarify a couple things:  1) Does `object('key')` therefore automatically generate for the given uploaded file?  (In other words, do I need to supply a 'key' or does the above code make one for me?)  2) Do I need to somehow assign ownership to my IAM user to access a particular bucket?  (In case it matters, I'm using Heroku rather than EC2)  Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure i a key would be generated if you didn't supply it; I always supply it. Easy enought to give it a try though. IAM Users will need to be given access to buckets, unless you've already made the public public for all users to read/write - not recommended,